# Spring 2.5 Ajax 1.7, updater receive wrong response

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 2.5, and use Ajax.updater (1.7) to get an response from an requestmapping in Spring.

In the request mapping I am returning an ModelAndView which refers to an jsp with some text. But the problem is that when ajax received the response and update the container, the entire page is wrapped in the container instead just the jsp output, why is this

Comment: A long time ago I used ajax with spring mvc 2.5. It many things you need to implement to use ajax. Do you have chance to use Spring MVC 3.x ajax with Spring 3.x is more easier.

Comment: Unfortunatly I need to use 2.5 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is how I used ajax with Spring 2.5

First of all you need controller to respond on ajax calls

```
public class AjaxController extends MultiActionController {

    // injected services, daos here

    public ModelAndView getAjaxData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        String data = // construct your ajax response here - string, json, xml etc
        model.put("data", data);
        return new ModelAndView("ajax_foo", model);
    }

     public ModelAndView anotherMethod(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        String data = // construct your ajax response here - string, json, xml etc
        model.put("data", data);
        return new ModelAndView("ajax_foo", model);
    }

}
```

Then you need ajaxView to write ajax data to response

```
public class AjaxView extends AbstractView {

    @Override
    protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map map, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        String ajaxResponse = map.get("data");     
        response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
        response.getOutputStream().write(ajaxResponse.getBytes());

}
```

View resolver to resolve ajax calls

```
public class AjaxViewResolver extends AbstractCachingViewResolver {

    private String ajaxPrefix;
    private View ajaxView;

    @Override
    protected View loadView(String viewName, Locale locale) throws Exception {
        View view = null;
        if (viewName.startsWith(this.ajaxPrefix)) {
            view = ajaxView;
        } else {

        }
        return view;
    }

    public void setAjaxPrefix(String ajaxPrefix) {
        this.ajaxPrefix = ajaxPrefix;
    }

    public void setAjaxView(View ajaxView) {
        this.ajaxView = ajaxView;
    }
}
```

Url mapping, map ajax url to ajax controller

```
<bean id="simpleUrlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
         <props>
            <prop key="/getAjaxData.htm">ajaxController</prop>
            <prop key="/anotherMethod.htm">ajaxController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Controller has bean ajaxResolver as methodNameResolver, controller has some services or daos for example

```
  <bean name="ajaxController" class="my.test.web.ajax.AjaxController">
        <property name="service" ref="service"/>
        <property name="dao" ref="dao"/>
        <property name="methodNameResolver" ref="ajaxResolver"/>
    </bean>
```

Method name resolver

```
<bean id="ajaxResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.PropertiesMethodNameResolver">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/getAjaxData.htm">getAjaxData</prop>
                <prop key="/anotherMethod.htm">anotherMethod</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Ajax View resolver to call your ajax view when you return modelAndView from AjaxController

```
 <bean id="ajaxViewResolver" class="my.test.web.ajax.AjaxViewResolver">
        <property name="ajaxView">
            <bean class="my.test.web.ajax.AjaxView"/>
        </property>
        <property name="ajaxPrefix" value="ajax_"/>
    </bean>
```